# Design issue when converting Oracle Forms to JSP

Tags: java, jsp, stored-procedures

I am new to Java programming and am required to convert Oracle Forms features into Java web application.  The design issue I have encountered is as follows:

The codes in the Oracle Forms are as follows:

```
Procedure PR_Store_Date(...)               

BEGIN
     FOR nCol1 in 1..7 LOOP  
      PR_Check_Day_Closing (V_From_Date, :Control.School_Code, Faccode,
                            V_Cl_Flag, V_Flag3);

      If (V_Cl_Flag = TRUE) then
          PR_Open_Close(Faccode, V_Flag2, V_Open_Cl_Flag, :Control3.From_Time,
                        :Control3.To_Time, V_From_Date, :Control3.Day);
      End If;

      If (V_flag2 = TRUE) AND (V_Cl_Flag = TRUE) then
               :
               :
      End If;

    END LOOP;
END;

Procedure PR_Check_Day_Closing (cValue    IN  DATE,
                                SCHCODE   IN  VARCHAR2,
                                FACCODE   IN  VARCHAR2,
                                V_Cl_Flag OUT BOOLEAN,
                                V_CHECK1  OUT BOOLEAN)
Begin
        :
        :
            If (nCnt3 >= 1) then
               Set_Application_Property(Cursor_Style, 'DEFAULT');
               Set_Alert_Property('CANCEL_OPEN_CLOSE_ALERT', ALERT_MESSAGE_TEXT,
                                  'Facility ' || faccode ||
                                  ' Closed for Booking. Do You Want to Overwrite ' ||
                                  'For the Day ' || TO_CHAR(cValue, 'DD-MON-YYYY') || ' ?');
               Bell; al_button := Show_Alert('CANCEL_OPEN_CLOSE_ALERT');

               If (al_button = ALERT_BUTTON1) then
                  V_Cl_Flag := TRUE;
               ElsIf (al_button = ALERT_BUTTON2) then
                  V_Cl_Flag := FALSE;
               End If;
            Else
               V_Cl_Flag := TRUE;
               v_Check1  := TRUE;
            End If;
           End If;
      End If;
End
```

And the same goes for PR_Open_Close.
Is it possible to achieve the same functionality using Java/JSP?  I have yet to find a best way to achieve the same results.

Hope this helps to clarify the question.  Thanks once again!

Comment: Thanks for helping to edit the question!!! Am really sorry for the lousy formatting

Answer (score 0):

In java web apps (or web apps in general) are three basic ways to interact with the user:

1) Submit:

Send the needed info to the server, then the server can generate another web page (or other), with a jsp in your case.

It can be done putting a submit button in html or submiting directly with javascript.

2) Javascript:

If you can load all the info into a single web page you can use javascript in a lot of ways to interact with the user without get any data from the server.

3) AJAX:

A "mix" from the other two. If you want to get data from the server but don't want to submit (don't want to reload the webpage).

AJAX is basically javascript code that call the server to retrieve more info.

I sugest you to check DWR, that is a very simple implementation of AJAX.